# What is the traditional Jewish name for this dish?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

My wife's minhag (that she made up bli nedder) is to make chicken stuffed wontons for the family Purim Seuda.

This year she decided to dig deeper into the minhag she made up last Thursday and made the wontons in a triangular shape, to appear more Hamentashin-like.

Now we are left wondering what the traditional Jewish name for this is.

Wontashin? Or Wontontashin?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Just curious. Is this really so unfunny to get all these downvotes?

Comment: Ah say der boy! You can't make chickentash without includin' me! (That's a joke, son. Nice boy, but a bit slow.)

Comment: @DanF Ah say ah say ah say boy chicken-tashin sho sounds like a good name. But yo gonna have to cross this line in the dirt to get some of em...

Answer (score 5):

"Stuffed Chicken Fingers In Ears"

Comment: I must admit, I am befuddled.

Comment: @user6591 you would prefer "

אוזני גחמן"? (Wanton ears?)

Comment: I'll admit my knowledge of Israeli culture is lacking. I didn't realize people call hamentashen haman ears. Took me a while. Now I get it. +1 and oznei gachaman is actual quite funny!

Answer (score 2):

Kreplach! updated for the 21st century.

Comment: Got a chuckle out of me:)

Answer (score 1):

I would call them *Ofnayim* in Hebrew, אופניים

It's a play on words / homophones.

אופן means "how", "type" or "way". Well, your wife has a strange type of wonton, or way to make hamantaschen  / wonton, whatever...

עוף is the word used for "chicken".

If you like the name, use it, and when you have a chance, after Purim, wire me your payment for using this "patented" name...

Answer (score 1):

The *act of eating them* would be called "noshin' on wontons."